# create external datasource in wso2esb

Tags: postgresql, wso2, datasource, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.8.0 and wish to create external datasource.I had tried default datasource and it's working fine now trying to create external datasource.For that added following configuration in `/home/wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/conf/datasources` :

```
<datasource>
    <name>DS1</name>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>DS1</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
 <configuration>
           <bean id="xaDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean">
            <dataSourceProps>
                <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</property>
                <property name="uniqueResourceName">TXDB1</property>
                <property name="xaProperties.user">youtilitydba</property>
                <property name="xaProperties.password">Youtility11</property>
                <property name="xaProperties.URL">jdbx:postgresql:/localhost:5432/DB1</property>
            </dataSourceProps>
</bean>
 </configuration>
   </definition>
</datasource>
```

and then added this datasource in proxy service as:

```
       <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <dsName>DS1</dsName>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>
                       select name,id,price from table1</sql>
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
```

and while executing this proxy found error as:

```
ERROR - DBLookupMediator Error executing statement : 
                       select name,id,price from table1 against DataSource : DS1
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
.
.
```

Is their any problem in proxy or datasource configuration is wrong? Let me know..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: if i use default datasource for same proxy then it works but the problem is only with external datasource.

Comment: Did you followed the instructions on [1],

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Configuring+an+RDBMS+Datasource